# Jacobi's Elliptic functions - Kernel

Tags: integral-kernel, elliptic-functions

I have an integral equation with a kernel expressed in terms of Jacobi's elliptic functions. In particular I want to solve the following equation:

$$\lambda \begin{pmatrix} X_1(u) \\ X_2(u) \end{pmatrix}= -k \int_{K+ i K'/2}^{-K+ i K'/2} dv \,\rho(u,v) \begin{pmatrix} X_1(v) \\ X_2(v) \end{pmatrix} $$
with $k$ the elliptic modulus and $\mathrm{sn}(u ; k) = \mathrm{sn}\, u$ Jacobi's elliptic sine.

$\rho$ is a matrix with the following entries

$$\begin{eqnarray}
&\rho_{11}(u,v)&=\frac{1- k\, \mathrm{sn}\, u \ \mathrm{sn}\, v}{\mathrm{sn}\, u-k\, \mathrm{sn}\, v},\nonumber\\
&\rho_{12}(u,v)&=\frac{\mathrm{sn}\, u - \mathrm{sn}\, v}{1- \mathrm{sn}\, u \,\mathrm{sn}\, v},\nonumber\\
&\rho_{21}(u,v)&=-\frac{k (\mathrm{sn}\, u - \mathrm{sn}\, v)}{1-k^2 \,\mathrm{sn}\, u\, \mathrm{sn}\, v}, \nonumber\\
&\rho_{22}(u,v)&=-\frac{1 - k\, \mathrm{sn}\, u\, \mathrm{sn}\, v}{k\, \mathrm{sn}\, u- \mathrm{sn}\, v}.
\end{eqnarray} $$

From consistency, one can simplify the matrix structure of the problem and instead solve for
$$\lambda \ X_1(u) = -k \int_{K- i K'/2}^{-K+ i K'/2} dv \ \rho_{11}(u,v)  X_1(v) -k \int_{-K- i K'/2}^{K- i K'/2} dv \ \rho_{11}(u,v)  X_1(v)  $$

How should one proceed to find the  eigen-functions of this problem?

Edit: Working the problem a bit one finds that the Integral equation and the eigenfunctions have the following properties:

1) $X(u+2 i K')= X(u)$.

2) $X(-u)=X(u+2K)$.

3) The odd/even $X(u)\pm X(-u)$ are again eigenfunctions with the same kernel.

4) Using $\int_{C_1+C_2} $ for the two contours of integration above,  $$ \lambda \ X(0)= \lambda \ X(2 m K + 2 i n K')=  \int_{C_1+C_2} \frac{X(v)}{ \mathrm{sn}\, v}  $$

5) $$ \lambda \ X(i K')= X(2 m K + i (2n+1) K')= k^2 \int_{C_1+C_2} \mathrm{sn}\, v \ X(v)  $$

6) $ \lambda \ X(K) = - k \int_{C_1+C_2} X(v)  $

7)  The following equations hold:
$$\lambda\left(  X(u) + X(u+2K) \right)= -2 k\int_{C_1+C_2} 
k\ \mathrm{sn}\, v \ \mathrm{cn}^2 u \ \frac{X(v)}{\mathrm{dn}^2 v - \mathrm{cn}^2 u} \\
\lambda\left(  X(u) - X(u+2K) \right)= -2 k\int_{C_1+C_2} \mathrm{sn}\, u \ \mathrm{dn}^2 v\ \frac{X(v)}{\mathrm{dn}^2 v - \mathrm{cn}^2 u}
$$

8) Finally from this last form one can combine the two contours into one and find the following integral equation for $X_{+}$
$$\lambda  X_{+}(u) = -2 k^2 \int_{C_1} 
\frac{  \mathrm{sn}\, v \ \mathrm{cn}^2 u  X_{+}(v)}{\mathrm{dn}^2 v - \mathrm{cn}^2 u}
$$
and a similar for $X_{-}$

Is there any reference that treats similar integral equations?? (Typically I would expect that one should write the kernel as a function $K_1(u-v)+K_2(u+v)$ and then solve by Fourier transform, but I do not know if this is possible in this case..

Comment: Hi Panos! :) To clarify your notation a bit: why is the ±
in the last formula in parentheses?

Comment: Hi Jules!! I used this not so good notation to indicate that the parenthesis on the right hand side corresponds to the two choices $\pm$ of signs of the left hand side.

Comment: Also note the imbalance (in modulus) of the two terms in the denominator, which is also there in the original form of the kernel...

Comment: Alright, I just turned it into two equations to make the meaning clear.